# Woocommerce category show subcategories only/omit posts for specific category

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a woocommerce shop with 2000+ products. I have set the shop catalog to show subcategories AND products. However, there are some categories that are so vague that there is no need to show any products until customer narrows filter.

I would therefore like to omit products from said pages to help with page load speed and customer confusion.

Something like.

```
If category id = 123
echo
<style>
.subcategories-div {display:block}
.products-div {display:none}
</style>
```

But then obviously, not do it via css.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try adding products to subcategory, but not showing them on main categories. Then when user filters and goes to subc, you show products.

[Link](https://www.themelocation.com/hide-subcategory-products-from-main-category-in-woocommerce/)

Comment: hi, this does not work for me. This omits products in general if they are part of a child category. This is not what I am looking for.